# Convert bigger dimension matrix to smaller dimension matrix with a loop

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I currently have **185*185 matrix** and the goal is to convert this matrix into a **35*35 matrix** by aggregating the value based on the rows and cols of the 185 matrix.

Example:

- I have a 8*8 matrix as below:

```
matrix_x <- matrix(1:64, nrow = 8)
```

- Then I want to convert it into a 4*4 matrix:

```
matrix_y <- matrix(NA, nrow = 4, ncol = 4)
```

- The list below is created for aggregating the 8*8 matrix cols to a 4*4 matrix

```
col_list <- list(
  1,
  2:3,
  c(4,8),
  5:7
)
```

- What I've done to achieve this is by assigning the value manually as below

```
matrix_y[1,1] <- sum(matrix_x[col_list[[1]],col_list[[1]]])
matrix_y[1,2] <- sum(matrix_x[col_list[[1]],col_list[[2]]])
matrix_y[1,3] <- sum(matrix_x[col_list[[1]],col_list[[3]]])
matrix_y[1,4] <- sum(matrix_x[col_list[[1]],col_list[[4]]])

matrix_y[2,1] <- sum(matrix_x[col_list[[2]],col_list[[1]]])
matrix_y[2,2] <- sum(matrix_x[col_list[[2]],col_list[[2]]])
matrix_y[2,3] <- sum(matrix_x[col_list[[2]],col_list[[3]]])
matrix_y[2,4] <- sum(matrix_x[col_list[[2]],col_list[[4]]])

matrix_y[3,1] <- sum(matrix_x[col_list[[3]],col_list[[1]]])
matrix_y[3,2] <- sum(matrix_x[col_list[[3]],col_list[[2]]])
matrix_y[3,3] <- sum(matrix_x[col_list[[3]],col_list[[3]]])
matrix_y[3,4] <- sum(matrix_x[col_list[[3]],col_list[[4]]])

matrix_y[4,1] <- sum(matrix_x[col_list[[4]],col_list[[1]]])
matrix_y[4,2] <- sum(matrix_x[col_list[[4]],col_list[[2]]])
matrix_y[4,3] <- sum(matrix_x[col_list[[4]],col_list[[3]]])
matrix_y[4,4] <- sum(matrix_x[col_list[[4]],col_list[[4]]])
```

This approach works well, but I'm looking for a more efficient way to achieve this since the approach I've done takes so many code lines.

Comment: Your code is not reproducible, so I am not sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm also confused. What's the point of quoting the sequences, e.g. `"1":"36"`? Why not `1:36`? What is `col_list` supposed to do? It might help to take a step back and construct a *minimal* example; try giving an example with a smaller input `matrix` (you currently don't seem to include *any* sample data).

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment. I've updated the question so hopefully you can understand what I'm trying to do. I'm quoting the sequences because if I don't it returns wrong calculation since it ignores a column which has all zeros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a neater/easier way to do this but here is one straight-forward option :

```
n <- 4
t(sapply(seq_len(n), function(p) sapply(col_list, function(q) sum(matrix_x[p, q]))))

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1   26   82  123
#[2,]    2   28   84  126
#[3,]    3   30   86  129
#[4,]    4   32   88  132
```

This gives the same matrix as `matrix_y` in the post.

---

For the updated question, we can use `outer`

```
apply_fun <- function(x, y) sum(matrix_x[x, y])
outer(col_list, col_list, Vectorize(apply_fun))

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1   26   82  123
#[2,]    5   58  170  255
#[3,]   12   72  184  276
#[4,]   18  108  276  414
```

Or following the same approach as in original answer with nested `sapply`

```
t(sapply(col_list, function(p) sapply(col_list, function(q) sum(matrix_x[p, q]))))
```

Comment: Hi Ronak, thank you for the answer. But apologize I gave a wrong example, it supposed to be sum(matrix_x[col_list[[1]],col_list[[1]]]) not sum(matrix_x[1,col_list[[1]]])

Comment: @doo Updated the answer, you can check the last part.

Comment: Nice solution with `outer`, liked it! I was writing the `outer` one as well but saw yours is already there, so deleted mine :)